# Is document.ready() function necessary while writing code using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, jsom

I am trying to get list and Add fields into it using JSOM.
In code below I'm using $(function(){}) i.e. $(document).ready() function.

```
button id="addField"
```

```
$(function () {
 $("#addField").click(function () {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('CustomList');
    this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'Product\' Type=\'Number\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);

    var fieldNumber = clientContext.castTo(oField, SP.FieldNumber);
    fieldNumber.update();

    clientContext.load(oField);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   });
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var result = oField.get_title() + ' added.';
    alert(result);
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var result = oList.get_title() + ' created.';
    alert(result);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
});
```

So could I use ready function in JSOM code before bind any event.
If we can use $(function()) then give a sample code which would be useful.

Comment: What is the issue?
Do you want any reference or what?
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: jQuery Ready function is only required if you want to update something in the DOM, if your script is executed before the DOM is available it can execute, just not do anything with DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can load that, but you'll need to wait until sp.js is loaded properly before using `SP.Context`. You can 'tee' up the function if you using the `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', yourFunction);`